# AWS S3 POST Policy content-length-range doesn't work for exact file size match

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I'd like to add file size validation to our signed urls, making sure the client uploads a file of **exactly** the size I signed it with.
However, when I do this :

```
"conditions": [
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    .... ,
    ["content-length-range", 1024, 1024]
]
```

For small files, it works.
But a bit larger files, for example 25mb, it results in **EntityTooSmall** error.

It starts working only if I set the minimum to 0 like this :

```
["content-length-range", 0, 1024]
```

But I want to enforce a specific file size, and not a range.
Does S3 not support **exact** file size match?

**EDIT :**
Here's the full code I compiled in Python :

```
# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id="...",
    aws_secret_access_key="...",
    region_name="sfo3",
    endpoint_url="https://sfo3.digitaloceanspaces.com",
)

# Specify the bucket name
bucket_name = 'my_bucket'

# Specify the file name
file_name = 'SampleJPGImage_30mbmb.jpeg'

# Get the file size in bytes
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)

# Use the file size and content
print("File size:", file_size, "bytes") # Should be 30789588

# Specify the desired file size in bytes
file_size_min = file_size
file_size_max = file_size

# Sign the policy with your AWS secret key
signedPolicy = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=file_name,
    Fields={
        "acl": "public-read",
        "key": file_name,
    },
    Conditions=[
        {"acl": "public-read"},
        {"key": file_name},
        ["content-length-range", file_size_min, file_size_max]
    ],
    ExpiresIn=3600
)

# Use the signed policy to upload the file
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
    print()
    resp = requests.post(signedPolicy['url'], data=signedPolicy['fields'], files={'file': f})
    print(resp)
    print(resp.content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to test with Postman an exact file size and everything is working correctly.
The condition that I used is:

```
const Conditions = [
    ["content-length-range", 30789588, 30789588],
    ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"]
];
```

I downloaded the 30MB file from here: https://sample-videos.com/download-sample-jpg-image.php

When I change the size of the content length to 30789587 I get the following:

```
<Error>
    <Code>EntityTooLarge</Code>
    <Message>Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size</Message>
    <ProposedSize>30789588</ProposedSize>
    <MaxSizeAllowed>30789587</MaxSizeAllowed>
</Error>
```

And with a content length of 30789589:

```
<Error>
    <Code>EntityTooSmall</Code>
    <Message>Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size</Message>
    <ProposedSize>30789588</ProposedSize>
    <MinSizeAllowed>30789589</MinSizeAllowed>
</Error>
```

Test with the same file I used and let's see if it works for you.

**Edit**

Executing the Python code to DigitalOcean Spaces gave the same error: **EntityTooSmall** without any other information.

Executing the same code to AWS S3 is working correctly. Also, the error message, when I change the range, is more useful.

It seems something with the range is not implemented correctly in DigitalOcean Spaces

Comment: Just saw your edit, thank you! we'll try to report the problem to DigitalOcean.
Irritating how they messed up such a basic thing..

Comment: @BVtp Great. For now you can accept the answer. Also add the information you get from Digital Ocean to the question, so it can help other people with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. You can specify only a range. I would check if the file size limit is specified correctly. This error likely indicates that the calculation wasn't right.

To test it further, I'd suggest generating a file with the exact size using e.g. dd tool, like this

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test-file-1 bs=26214400 count=1
```

Then try to upload it. In this case, your range must be [26214400,26214400].

Comment: I did what you said, created a jpg file :
`dd if=/dev/zero of=test-file-1.jpg bs=26214400 count=1`

Then used `[26214400,26214400]` range, and I still got EntityTooSmall using Postman. What do you think the problem may be?

Comment: @BVtp Can you describe the process of how you upload the file using Postman?

Comment: @jellycsc yes, I've edited my post and added our python code including how we set up our DigitalOcean Spaces (S3) client, etc.